# Text appears under div with viewport sizing instead of inside div

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

This is my css:

```
.triangle-topright {
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 100vh 20vw 0vw 50vw;
       border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) rgba(255,255,255,0.5) rgba(255,255,255,0.5) transparent;
       position: relative;
       float: right;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="triangle-topright" >
      <h1>here</h1>
</div>
```

"here" appears under the div, but I want it to appear in the div, let's say in the middle, or wherever I choose. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div is `height: 0;`, so nothing can really appear "in" it. However, you're building a CSS triangle, so to heck with convention!

If you're saying you want the `h1` to appear in the middle of the div's top border, you could add this style rule and adjust the `top` property as necessary:

```
.triangle-topright h1 {
  position: absolute; // Works because .triangle-topright is position: relative
  top: -50vh; // Half of your vertical border space
  line-height: 1rem; // Make sure line height is predictable
  margin-top: -.5rem; // Center element on its Y axis (assuming only one line of text is involved)
  // You might need to zero out some margins or padding to achieve your desired result
}
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help.